# Where to get linux-headers-4.4.0-17134-Microsoft for Intel ICC compiler?

Tags: linux, windows, linux-kernel, icc

I'm installing Intel Parallel studio cluster on the LXSS on Windows 10 64 bits 17134. I'm asked to get kernel headers `linux-headers-4.4.0-17134-Microsoft` (in the debian/ubuntu case). Where can I get this ? (not mentioned by google)
Is it fine to use `linux-headers-4.4.0` instead ? My understanding is that there is a kernel interface translation *linux kernel-windows kernel*. Is it safe to use the standard header ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is a bit of a funny situation. Those header files don't technically exist, because there is no "4.4.0-17134-Microsoft" Linux kernel. The system is running on an NT kernel.

A standard set of Linux 4.4.0 headers (like the `linux-headers-4.4.0` package you mentioned) should be an appropriate substitute for most purposes. You won't be able to build kernel modules in this environment, though, as there is no Linux kernel to load them into.

Comment: I guess the name was auto-generated by Intel's installer. If there is a kernel's interface, programs don't care if it's a genuine kernel or not. In FreeBSD there is the same thing. And drivers go along with it. What are your arguments for "I won't be able to build kernel modules" ?

Comment: The LXSS emulation of Linux only extends to userspace interfaces. It doesn't attempt to emulate any kernel APIs, which would be required to load kernel modules. You could probably _build_ a kernel module, but you wouldn't be able to load it.

Comment: Is that the reason why I cannot call regular software interrupt in assembly (eg `int 0x80` for `exit()`) ?